# Upgrading CDH from 4.2.1 to CDH 4.3 without using cloudera manager

Tags: cloudera

I had install CDH 4.2.1 manually without using cloudera manager using the installation guide on http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/PDF/CDH4-Installation-Guide.pdf site.
Now i want to upgrade the version from 4.2.1 to 4.3 without using cloudera manager.Can anyone guide me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Cloudera Manager makes CDH installation and upgrades *so* much easier. It's worth installing for that reason alone (and it's included in the free Cloudera Standard package).

As you've already done a manual install however, a manual upgrade is the only realistic option --  [this doc](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_8.html) explains how.

Answer (score 0):

For upgrading CDH 4.2.1 to CDH 4.3 manually , you need to consider updating the different services running on cluster.
The parcels or packages you have downloaded while installations is of 4.2.1. In other words we can say these supports only 4.2.1 , so need to download rpm or packages of different services install it manually in your system. I have updated my system from CDH 3 to CDH 4.8. 
It's running in my case . Enjoy :)